# after install python 2.7.3 yum is broken

Tags: linux, yum

i installed libxml2-2.9.0 and libxslt-1.1.27 then yum is broken any yum command that i ran i got the result of :

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Jan 21 2009, 01:11:33) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

then i thought python version is way too old and install python 2.7.3 and install it from scratch, after some wrong trials it got worse and worse, now when i run 'python -V' i got version 'Python 2.7.3', when i run '/usr/bin/python -V', it returned 'python-2.4.3-24.el5', and no matter what i did the yum is still broken with that message. how can i get yum back? 
my os is: linux 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @ajreal Come on dude. Can one of you admins take the time to at least comment on why this is off topic, instead of just closing it with the stock message? Get off your ass and actually help the community. Don't bite newbs. Etc etc. I'm beginning to think all SO admins are A-holes.

Comment: This question should not have been closed... overzealous admins.

Comment: @SamGoldberg: they aren't admins, they're just users with close privileges (once you get 3000 reputation, you can [vote to close questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). Anyway, this question [appears to be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474393/there-is-some-problems-about-yum-after-update-python).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: thanks for the correction. so in other words, the correct way to close this question would have been as a duplicate, which would have been much more reasonable, as it would have given the OP an understandable reason to close (and pointer to solution).  However, "Off topic" is vague, subjective, and inconsistently applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the FAQ](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq#Q.7%3aIinstalledanewversionofyumorupgradedmywholesystemandnowwhenIrunyumIgetanerrorsayingTheyumlibrariesdonotseemtobeavailableonyoursystemforthisversionofpythonandPleasemakesurethepackageyouusedtoinstallyumwasbuiltforyourinstallofpython.WhatswrongwiththeyumpackageIvegotormyPythoninstallationandhowdoIfixit):

> In pre-2.3.? yum This error message is often misleading. To see the
>   real error, run python from the command line, and type import yum. The
>   problem probably isn't with your version of python at all, but with a
>   missing libxml2-python, python-sqlite, or python-elementtree package.
>
> Yum 2.4.x provides a different error with the module import errors, so
>   this will become less confusing.
>
> It also includes a directive to send the error to the mailing list.
>   Really, you should figure out what rpm provides the module that was
>   missing and try to install that.
>
> If you are getting a message that yum itself is the missing module
>   then you probably installed it incorreclty (or installed the source
>   rpm using make/make install). If possible, find a prebuilt rpm that
>   will work for your system like one from Fedora or CentOS. Or, you can
>   download the srpm and do a
>
> rpmbuild --rebuild yum*.src.rpm

So, if else fails, you can get the yum package somewhere like [this](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=yum).